# Inkscape (Tex Text) not working with mathbbm as expected

Tags: inkscape

The bbm package is giving bad styling for the indicator function when attempting to use Tex Text:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: I do not know if this is helpful, but `bbm` is actually a pixel font, so it may not be suitable for `inkscape` for this reason. You could try `dsfont` instead, which is not pixelated, but also not as ugly (this is my opinion) of the AMS doublestroke fonts, i.e. it looks a bit like `bbm` but is not pixelated.

Comment: Thanks! The dsfont version worked a treat.